# How can I do multiple lookups in R?

Tags: r

So I have file kit.txt like this (it's all on one line):

```
"bbc_a#22292", "bbc_b#22293", "desert8#5394", "city4#2525",
```

And I have stores.txt like this (it's all in one line):

```
["22292"] = {"bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482", "bbc/images/station.jpg#517482"}, ["5394"] = {"bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499"}, ["432112"] = {"bbc/images/sunset.mp3#53209", "bbc/images/alert.mp3#51109"},
```

And I have area.txt like this (one row per line):

```
bbc/images/auction.jpg;52
bbc/images/sunrise.jpg;38
bbc/images/stars.jpg;46
```

What I'm trying to do is, for each row in kit.txt, the ID from kit.txt should be looked up in stores.txt (first column in braces).  If the ID exists, the title from stores.txt (the text before the hash symbol) should be looked up in area.txt.  If the title exists in area.txt, then it should be output to a file like this with the title, stores ID and area ID shown (one row per line):

```
"bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482#52",
"bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499#38",
```

Using the quotes and commas as shown.  So only auction and sunrise are included because only they exist in both kit.txt and stores.txt.

How can I do this in R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform some cleaning of all the files so that they are in usable format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#Read and clean 'kit.txt'
read.table('kit.txt', sep = ';') %>%
  separate_rows(V1, sep = ',\\s+') %>%
  separate(V1, c('V1', 'V2'), sep = '#') %>%
  mutate(V2 = sub(',$', '', V2)) -> d1

d1
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  V1      V2   
#  <chr>   <chr>
#1 bbc_a   22292
#2 bbc_b   22293
#3 desert8 5394 
#4 city4   2525 

#Read and clean 'stores.txt'
read.table('stores.txt', sep = '@') %>%
  separate_rows(V1, sep = ',\\s\\[') %>%
  separate(V1, c('V1', 'V2'), sep = '\\s=\\s') %>%
  separate_rows(V2, sep = ',\\s') %>%
  mutate(V2 = gsub('\\{|\\}', '', V2), 
         V1 = trimws(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', V1))) %>%
  separate(V2, c('V2', 'V3'), sep = '#') %>%
  mutate(V3 = sub(',$', '',V3)) -> d2

d2
#   V1     V2                     V3    
#  <chr>  <chr>                  <chr> 
#1 22292  bbc/images/auction.jpg 567482
#2 22292  bbc/images/station.jpg 517482
#3 5394   bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 567499
#4 432112 bbc/images/sunset.mp3  53209 
#5 432112 bbc/images/alert.mp3   51109 

#read area.txt
d3 <- read.table('area.txt', sep = ';')

d3
#                      V1 V2
#1 bbc/images/auction.jpg 52
#2 bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 38
#3   bbc/images/stars.jpg 46

#combine d1, d2 and d3
d1 %>%
  inner_join(d2, by = c('V2' = 'V1')) %>%
  inner_join(d3, by = c('V2.y' = 'V1')) -> result

result

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  V1      V2.x  V2.y                   V3     V2.y.y
#  <chr>   <chr> <chr>                  <chr>   <int>
#1 bbc_a   22292 bbc/images/auction.jpg 567482     52
#2 desert8 5394  bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 567499     38

#Write the file
cat(sprintf('"%s#%s#%s",', result$V2.y, result$V3, result$V2.y.y), file = 'result.lua', sep = '\n')
```

For the example shared, the same output can be achieved without using `'kit.txt'` as well.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed something out.  This works unless stores.txt contains more one element inside the table.  Example, if stores.txt contains this ["12345"] = {"bbca#568128", "bbcb#568493"} then the script fails with an error 'Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [2]' and db2 contains invalid data.  I'm sorry that was my fault for not stating that stores.txt can often contain more than 1 element inside each table.  I updated my question in the stores.txt section.

Comment: How do I fix this so that it works with multiple elements inside a table in stores.txt?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to swap the slashes over in your code so I swapped the slashes in the code that creates stores.txt (that's another file) and it's working beautifully now.  I did need to add , quote="\"" to area.txt as before because it contains single quotes.  I respect your reasoning for not updating a second time as I haven't been the best with my questions.  It's just that it takes a long time to test as the data files can contain a million lines but I can only submit a few lines here.  Thanks again for your wonderful and swift answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt.

```
$ cat file1.txt
"bbc_a#22292", "bbc_b#22293", "desert8#5394", "city4#2525"
$ cat file2.txt
["22292"] = {"bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482"}, ["5394"] = {"bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499"}, ["432112"] = {"bbc/images/sunset.mp3#53209"}
$ cat file3.txt
bbc/images/auction.jpg;52
bbc/images/sunrise.jpg;38
bbc/images/stars.jpg;46



# Reading in the files as vectors.

v1 <- scan("file1.txt",what = character(),sep=",")
v2 <- scan("file2.txt",what=character(),sep=",")
v3 <- scan("file3.txt",what = character(),sep="\n")

# Making dataframes from the vectors

library(stringr)
df1 <- str_split_fixed(v1,"#",2)
df2 <- str_split_fixed(v2,"=",2)
df3 <- str_split_fixed(v3,";",2)


> df1
     [,1]       [,2]   
[1,] "bbc_a"    "22292"
[2,] " bbc_b"   "22293"
[3,] " desert8" "5394" 
[4,] " city4"   "2525" 
> df2
     [,1]         [,2]                              
[1,] "[22292] "   " {bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482}"
[2,] " [5394] "   " {bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499}"
[3,] " [432112] " " {bbc/images/sunset.mp3#53209}"  
> df3
     [,1]                     [,2]
[1,] "bbc/images/auction.jpg" "52"
[2,] "bbc/images/sunrise.jpg" "38"
[3,] "bbc/images/stars.jpg"   "46"
> 
library(dplyr)

df1 <- mutate_all(data.frame(df1),list(trimws))
> df1
       X1    X2
1   bbc_a 22292
2   bbc_b 22293
3 desert8  5394
4   city4  2525
> 

df2 <- mutate_all(data.frame(df2), list(trimws))
> df2
        X1                              X2
1  [22292] {bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482}
2   [5394] {bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499}
3 [432112]   {bbc/images/sunset.mp3#53209}
> 

df2 <- mutate_all(df2,str_sub,2,-2)
> df2
      X1                            X2
1  22292 bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482
2   5394 bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499
3 432112   bbc/images/sunset.mp3#53209
> 
df4 <- str_split_fixed(df2$X2,"#",2)
> df4
     [,1]                     [,2]    
[1,] "bbc/images/auction.jpg" "567482"
[2,] "bbc/images/sunrise.jpg" "567499"
[3,] "bbc/images/sunset.mp3"  "53209" 
> 
df2<- df2[,1]
df2 <- cbind(df2,df4)
> df2
     df2                                       
[1,] "22292"  "bbc/images/auction.jpg" "567482"
[2,] "5394"   "bbc/images/sunrise.jpg" "567499"
[3,] "432112" "bbc/images/sunset.mp3"  "53209" 
> 
kit <- as_tibble(df1)
colnames(df2)<-NULL
store <- as_tibble(df2)
area <- as_tibble(df3)
> kit
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  X1      X2   
  <chr>   <chr>
1 bbc_a   22292
2 bbc_b   22293
3 desert8 5394 
4 city4   2525 
> store
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  V1     V2                     V3    
  <chr>  <chr>                  <chr> 
1 22292  bbc/images/auction.jpg 567482
2 5394   bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 567499
3 432112 bbc/images/sunset.mp3  53209 
> area
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  V1                     V2   
  <chr>                  <chr>
1 bbc/images/auction.jpg 52   
2 bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 38   
3 bbc/images/stars.jpg   46   
> 
j1 <- inner_join(kit,store,by =c("X2"="V1"))

> j1
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  X1      X2    V2                     V3    
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>                  <chr> 
1 bbc_a   22292 bbc/images/auction.jpg 567482
2 desert8 5394  bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 567499
> 

j2 <- inner_join(j1,area,by = c("V2"="V1" ))

> j2
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  X1      X2    V2                     V3     V2.y 
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>
1 bbc_a   22292 bbc/images/auction.jpg 567482 52   
2 desert8 5394  bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 567499 38   
> 
answer <- j2[,c(3:5)]
> answer
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  V2                     V3     V2.y 
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>
1 bbc/images/auction.jpg 567482 52   
2 bbc/images/sunrise.jpg 567499 38   
> 
colnames(answer)<- c("C1","C2","C3")

paste(answer$C1,answer$C2,answer$C3,sep="#")

[1] "bbc/images/auction.jpg#567482#52" "bbc/images/sunrise.jpg#567499#38
```

Comment: I'm sorry I missed something out. This works unless stores.txt contains more one element inside the table. Example, if stores.txt contains this ["12345"] = {"bbca#568128", "bbcb#568493"} then the script fails with an error 'Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with NA in 1 rows [2]' and db2 contains invalid data. I'm sorry that was my fault for not stating that stores.txt can often contain more than 1 element inside each table.  I updated my question in the stores.txt section.

Comment: How do I fix this so that it works with multiple elements inside a table in stores.txt?